# Removing noise on Matlab

Tags: filter, noise, matlab, snr

I chose a sine signal, let's say : Us=2*sin(2*pi*Fs*t) with Fs=800 !
 Then I introduced a random noise to this signal.
 The aim of my program is to increase the SNR.
 The first method was to increase the amplitude of the signal, and it worked. (My SNR before was something like 9, when I took as an amplitude 5, the SNR jumped to 14)
 The second method was trying to reduce noise and I thought of a filter, Butterworth's for instance. On the plot, it was very very clear that the noise was less, but when I calculated the SNR it barely increased by 0.5 . I took as cutting frequency 6000, is this where the problem lies ? 
Are there other solutions to remove this noise ?

Thank you !

Comment: Oh, well, I think I know what the problem is :
Here is the program I wrote : 
Fs=800;
t = (0:3*Fs)'/Fs;
n= .5*randn(size(t));
Us1 = 2*sin(2*pi*t);
s1 = Us1+n;
N=8000;
[b,a]=butter(2,810/N/2);
denoised=filter(b,a,s1);
RMS = @(x) sqrt(mean(x.^2));
s_snr_db = @(x) 20 * log10( RMS(x) / RMS(n) );
s_snr_db1 = s_snr_db(s1);
s_snr_db2 = s_snr_db(denoised);
subplot(1,2,1); plot(t,s1,'r');
title(['Amplitude A=2; snr=',num2str(s_snr_db1)]);
subplot(1,2,2); plot(t,denoised);
title(['Amplitude A=2; snr=',num2str(s_snr_db2)]);

It looks like the problem lies in the function that calculates SNR, right ?

Comment: I sound like a psych, but I've just found out the answer ! I've been thinking about this all day long but to no avail ! As soon as I posted the question, I found the answer ! Sorry to bother you all, this post can be deleted :)

Comment: No need to delete, you can post an answer to your own question then accept it.

Answer (score 1):

If your signal is just at 800 Hz, and your noise is 'white' (spread all over the spectrum), your filter (low pass, I assume) at 60 kHz still takes a lot of noise with your signal. Try with a narrow band pass (750 to 850 Hz) and you'll see wonders.